# How to open a boostrap modal from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

how can i open a modal using anchors the scenario is this

The anchor tag is in the index.php and the anchor tag goes to another page and open the modal ? how can i do that ?

```
<div class="messassge">
  <a href="profile.php/#myModal" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this link : `profile.php?myModal=on`.

In `profile.php`, retriveve the `$_GET['myModal']` and pass it to the jquery function that triggers the modal open.

Something like this:

```
$("#myModal").css({"display": "<?php if( $_GET['myModal'] == 'on' ){ echo 'block';}else{ echo 'none';} ?>"});
```

I didn't see your modal trigger... So this is an example.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery check if url hash matches modal element and if it does open it

```
if(location.hash){
  var $modal = $(location.hash);
  if($modal.hasClass('modal')){
     $modal.modal();
  }
}
```